Google Sheets showing "invalid call to unknown function"
I am trying to make a table consisting of X values, f(x) values, and g(x) values. Here is a desmos graph of the two functions: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vint4ossia. (They are in blue). while I did get f(x) down into google sheets, g(x) is giving me errors. 
Here is the g(x) function I made plugged in for A2. (ie substituting A2 for x).
= (0.5 * csc(pi()+6)* sec(pi()+6) * (A2-sqrt((A2^2) * (sin(pi()+6))^4+(A2^2) * (cos(pi()+6))^4 + 2 * A2^2 * (sin(pi()+6))^2 * (cos(pi()+6))^2 + 8 * A2 * (sin(pi()+6))^3 +2 * pi() * A2 * (cos(pi() + 6))^3 + 8 * A2 * (sin(pi() + 6)) * (cos(pi() + 6))^2 + 2 * pi() * A2 * (sin(pi()+6)) * cos(pi() + 6) + 16 * (sin(pi() + 6))^2 + (pi())^2 * (cos(pi() + 6))^2 + 8 * pi() * (sin(pi() + 6)) * cos(pi() + 6) - 4 * sin(pi() + 6) * cos(pi() + 6)) - A2 * (sin(pi() + 6))^2 + A2 * (cos(pi() + 6))^2 - 4 * sin (pi() + 6) + pi() * cos(pi() + 6)))
it is definitely messy because I defined the function implicitly and then had to convert it into a "y=" form. If someone could please spend some time on this it would be appreciated.
All functions are now fixed, but it throws a parameter error for square root "sqrt", which does not happen in desmos. Can someone please check it again?

arithmetic operator missing in this part? 8 * pi() (sin(pi() + 6))

Thanks! I wouldnt of been able to catch that. However, now it is throwing sqrt's domain is -1, which does not happen in the desmos graph. I will edit the question accordingly

Have you considered writing a real function, instead of a near-impossible to read cell evaluation? Give https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions a read, and then just implement the desmos code using JS, so you can take advantage of normal code editors (sublime, vs code, webstorm, etc) helping you find errors in your code.

I have now tried using JS, and sure, it is returning a result, but not the right one. Just as a question, do you think downloading a latex reader as an add on to google sheet will help? that way I can directly copy paste the desmos function into google sheets.
